# Registering the Service Principal Name

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-server-2019

Can someone explain me how I register SPN in Active Directory? The instruction below is from SAP Business One. But using the command **setspn -U -A** return an error, I'm using Windows Server 2019.

```
> On a Windows computer, run the command prompt as an administrator. Run
> the following setspn command: setspn -U -A <SPN> <Domain User Name>.
>
```

- An example of an SPN is SLD/Domain.com

So I used this command:

> PS C:\Users\Administrator> setspn -U MYLOCAL\SLD

Then i returns:

> Registered ServicePrincipalNames for
>   N=SLD,CN=Users,DC=mylocal,DC=internal:

Is it successfully registered now?

Thanks,

Comment: Your command didn't actually specify the SPN that you want to register, did it?

Comment: I really don't understand on what the instruction want. Can you please explain me this command: **setspn -U -A <SPN> <Domain User Name>** What would be the example value of <SPN>?

Comment: Well, you already gave an example in your own post ("SLD/Domain.com")... [See Microsoft documentation.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/service-principal-names) What is it that you _want_ to register?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setspn -L <object>` to verify which SPNs are resgitered for that object. You should also be able to use `setspn -Q <SPN>` to query for a given SPN and get a list of objects that got it.